# Dell Laptop runs only on powersaving

Tags: dell, power-management, battery

[image]My laptop is Inspiron 5570, OS: Ubuntu 21.04, My Battery is removed and the laptop runs on AC.

The issue is that I am stuck at powersave and unable to keep the system running on best performance

The power options at settings aren't working, I tried many TLP ( software Slimbook, cpufreq, CPU Power Manager, etc... ) but all didn't work, Bios options didn't solve the issue too.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'stuck in `powersave`'? Is that the current CPU governor?

Comment: @galexite yes, all my cores (8) are at 0.40GHz when Ever I star games. the issue really started when I removed my battery. sometimes when I run software like Krita( digital painting ) it does the same. Only browser really doesn't affect it.